# Python ValueError - Using Try:Except:Else to skip over section of code that has error

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a code that gets data from a number of sources, when one of the sources does not return any data I get:

"ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 13 elements"

When this happens I need to skip over that section of the code and replace it with an alternate code, and then continue on with the rest of the code.

I have looked at other examples, but they have not explained how to continue on with the rest of the code.

I have been trying to use:

```
Other code that is run before 

try:
   Get data..
except ValueError:
   Use this instead
else:
   Get data

Other code that is run after
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: usually there would be a loop of some kind. are you familiar with loops?

Comment: `Try` is not a valid python syntax. change it to `try`

Comment: Sorry typo in my question...I am using type:

Comment: I can do if loops, but try is new to me, as is error handling.

Comment: "if" is not a loop, it's a condition/branch. possible loops: "for", "while".

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, was formatting, not a problem with the use of try:...thanks for the help.